# Force Windows 10 to use a particular driver

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I have a USB device which is recognized as a COM port on Windows 10, but in order to work, I must force it to use a custom device driver (not signed).
This procedure works fine, but if I unplug this device and connect another sample, It's again recognized as a COM port (this didn't happened on Windows 7).

I already [disabled driver signature check](http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38289/~/windows-10%3A-disable-signed-driver-enforcement), and testing indicates that the port in which the device is connected doesn't matter:

- A device for which I manually selected the driver can be connected to any USB port and it will work.
- A device (same model) for which I let Windows install the driver, will always be detected as a COM port, no matter in which USB port I connect it.

Is there any way to tell Windows 10 to use the driver I want for every device having the same VID/PID, instead of the one built in one?

Comment: You are connecting it to the same port each time?  You have disabled the feature that requires signed device drivers I presume?

Comment: Same port, yes. It's displaying a warning about the driver not being signed when I force the driver, but it works fine after that. The problem is that win doesn't use that driver after I plug another device

Comment: I still don't know if have specifically enabled allowing unsigned drivers or not.

Comment: I did enabled unsigned drivers, as nothing would work without that. I followed the instructions from http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38289/~/windows-10%3A-disable-signed-driver-enforcement

Comment: Update your question

Answer (score 1):

To temporarily prevent the driver from being reinstalled until a new driver fix is available, a troubleshooter is available that provides a user interface to hide and show Windows updates and drivers for Windows 10.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3073930/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-driver-update-from-reinstalling-in-window